# Can there be a "random order"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

A recent article in the New York Times discussed the decision by the Metropolitan Museum of Art to eliminate the use of small metal buttons to signify that you have paid admission.

[image: met button]

The entrances are fairly open, and guards glance over the crowd to make sure you have the badge of a patron. All buttons on a given day are the same color. The color changes the next day so that one cannot return and enter without paying.

According to the Times,

> the colors are changed daily ***in random order***.

The Compact ODO defines *[order](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/order?q=order)* as

> the arrangement or disposition of people or things in relation to each other according to a particular sequence, pattern, or method

It defines *[random](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/random?q=random)* to mean

> made, done, happening, or chosen without method or conscious decision

Is this a mistake, a deliberate oxymoron, or is there a straightforward logical meaning to this phrase?

Comment: Look up *sequence* again. The numbers at roulette come up in a sequence, and also in random order.

Comment: This looks more like a peeve than a genuine question.

Comment: But it is a damn good motivated peeve! I checked *random* in the dictionary myself, and neither "a random selection" nor "random order" are listed. The only noun suggested is "sample" as in "*a random sample*". Not how I would define a reliable dictionary.

Comment: @TimLymington But why would the OP or any learner look up "sequence"? There is nothing to suggest that "order" needn't follow a logical sequence. I think we can all agree that random order is perfectly acceptable and a very common expression, if OD can allow themselves to ignore such a common expression what other idioms, expressions, uses have been omitted in the name of conciseness?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: because *sequence* is part of the definition he is having trouble with. And any dictionary that included *random order* would have to include millions of other two-word phrases.  *Random order* is no more idiomatic than *alphabetical order* or *reliable dictionary*; it is a simple adjective +noun.

Comment: Now, *here* is a tangent: You can enter the Met without paying, anyway. Unless things have changed recently (-ish), the entrance fee is a *suggested* donation - so, if you can live with the hostile sneers of the cashiers, you can "return and enter without paying".   You can even get a button for each day (well, that part is changing, obviously).

Comment: @snailboat In some places, this reference work is called the *Compact Oxford English Dictionary* but elsewhere the *Oxford Dictionary Online*. I have changed the reference to avoid confusion with the print or subscription OED.

Comment: ... hey now, bib!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Shakespeare notes, sometimes there's method in madness.

Yes, “random order” is an [oxymoron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxymoron) in that the two words are an apparent contradiction in terms: *order* suggests organization while *random* suggests a lack thereof. However, like many oxymora, the contradiction is incidental and resolvable by careful consideration. “Controlled chaos” is a similar oxymoron where lack of a method is part of the method.

To resolve the contradiction, first consider that order doesn't always mean **deliberate** order. The [natural order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_order_%28philosophy%29) is a well-known example, used in contrast to the laws of God and men, where philosophers base morality on the natural world as **observed** instead of a divine or mortal plan. [Spontaneous order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_order) is a similar example, where order emerges “out of seeming chaos.” This lies at the root of Tim Lymington's comment that sequence needn't imply deliberation.

Furthermore, the Oxford definition of *random* overlooks many subtleties of the word, as it's a dictionary and not a comprehensive treatment of the subject. While a [random](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness) order does imply a lack of conscious choice in selecting each **element** of the sequence, it does not speak to the choice of employing randomness in the overall method. The process is deliberate (and thus ordered) even if the outcome is not (and thus random).

I don't believe that this is a deliberate oxymoron – emphasis mine:

> In general, oxymora can be divided into expressions that were deliberately crafted to be contradictory and those phrases that inadvertently or incidentally contain a contradiction, **often as a result of a punning use of one or both words.**

Order includes both deliberate and observed sequences. Randomness can indicate a lack of a plan or simply an unpredictable outcome. “Random order” actually means “an observed sequence with unpredictable outcome.” The contradiction only arises incidentally, if you select the wrong meaning of **both** words to form “a deliberate lack of a plan,” making this an inadvertent oxymoron.

Answer (score 5):

Webster's Dictionary has:

1. the disposition of things following one after another

(one of 30 defined senses for the nounal use!)

So, without having to check whether 'sequence' demands a non-random arrangement or not, this sense licenses both prescribed and chance arrangements. And surely most people would acknowledge without having to check in a dictionary that 'shuffling changes the order of the cards in a pack'.

One definition given by a single dictionary is not adequate to base a treatise on.

Comment: I agree that is good practice to check definitions in more than one dictionary, but "random order" is hardly obscure and it's Oxford Dictionaries: "The world's most trusted dictionaries". I for one am quite startled by their omission.

Comment: It _was_ only the _Compact_ that was mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, there's not enough information to answer your question, but it's probably fine.

If each day's color is selected randomly at the moment that it is needed, you could make the case that there never exists a sequence of upcoming colors that could be in any kind of order (although this is really splitting hairs, to be honest). However, doing it this way creates the possibility that the same color could be used on two or more subsequent days, which is undesirable for a number of reasons. It seems likely, therefore, that at any given time the museum maintains a short "buffer" of unduplicating colors to be used on upcoming days, and that the sequence of colors in the buffer is indeed in *random order*.

Answer (score 0):

The answer? Change your online dictionary.

In [**free dictionary**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/random) for "random" it states:

> 1. Having no specific pattern, purpose, or objective: *random movements*. See Synonyms at [*chance.*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/chance)
>
> **Idiom:**
>    **at random**
>   Without a governing design, method, or purpose; unsystematically: *chose [sic?] a card at random from the deck.*
>
> n. **at random** in a purposeless fashion; not following any prearranged order
>
> Thesaurus: **Adj. 1. random** - lacking any definite plan or order
>   or purpose; governed by or depending on chance; "a random choice";
>   "bombs fell at random"; "random movements"

In [**Merriam-Webster**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/random) in *Examples of random* it has:

> "We tasted the wines in **random order** and then rated each."

"Random order" is perfectly acceptable and used in everyday situations. *Perhaps* it was once more correct to say:

- "the colors are changed daily **at random**."
- "the colors are changed **randomly** on a daily basis"
- "the colors are changed following **no specific order**"

But in none of the three dictionaries I consulted was there any mention that "random order" is considered non-standard or informal English.

.

Comment: So the definitions from Free-dictionary and Merriam Webster online dictionaries receive a vote-down because..?

Comment: Perhaps this is a bit late to respond to your comments, but *change your online dictionary* is never a helpful answer.  If OP really thinks 'according to a particular sequence, pattern, or method* **excludes** randomly, then he needs to do more research into what each of those words means; if he edits his question, we may be able to help more. But advising somebody who thinks the dictionary is wrong to find another dictionary is the very reverse of helpful advice, since it implies that he has as much right to decide on a definition as the lexicographer, which is almost certainly false.

Comment: @TimLymington you are not the first to point out, (Fumble-fingers was the first) that the first sentence in my answer is unhelpful and inappropriate. And after considering the matter I will concede that my answer appears to be rude, and possibly, be interpreted as a criticism towards the OP. Nothing further from the truth. I do believe, however, that the two resources I cited, both extremely well-known, demonstrate that "random order" as a phrase is not a mistake, nor a deliberate oxymoron.

Comment: But at the very least I now understand why my answer is considered inappropriate and incorrect, for which I do appreciate your comment. So, thank you for clearing up the "mystery". :)

Comment: The fact I understand why some people down-voted this answer (because of my perceived rudeness) doesn't justify a third anonymous down-vote (or is it fourth--I've lost count). The OP based his entire question on the poor and inadequate definitions of *random* and *order* in the concise Oxford dictionary. I don't give a damn if it's "Oxford" A name and reputation doesn't mean it's infallible. I merely pointed out that by using other online dictionaries the OP would have understood more clearly the meaning of "random order". So, continue down-voting this answer if it makes you feel better.

Comment: Mari-Lou: As I and others pointed out, this has been downvoted not because of your rudeness, personal opinions, or disagreement, but because it is a bad and unhelpful answer. Nobody can downvote more than once, so your stream of comments amount to "I am right and everybody else is wrong". You are better than that.

Comment: @TimLymington My "if it makes you feel better" is directed at anyone and everyone, but not at one individual. I know a user cannot down-vote more than once, and that's a huge relief! :-) I don't interpret my comments as saying: I am right, and everyone else is wrong. No... The references I posted are not my opinions, the definitions I "copied" are not my own. I'm having a little rant; I'm defending my answer, and I think I'm entitled to do so.

Comment: @TimLymington - in the interests of avoiding the fate of this answer could you possibly explain what makes it a "bad and unhelpful answer." Is the answer wrong? I ask because I believe I have already experienced similar responses to a couple of my posts. ps, I haven't voted oh this OP or any of the answers, though I will soon.

Comment: @LittleEva: Please read *all* my comments again, not just on this answer (the problem with coming to a discussion a year and a half in). Briefly: *random order* is indeed a perfectly good phrase, and the contradiction OP sees is apparent not real (as other answers say). But this answer either says or implies a) that the Compact Oxford is mistaken and b) that if the first dictionary you consult does not give the result you want, you just try another until you find one that does. A) is wrong; b) is arguable, but certainly does not apply here. Both are terrible advice to give to a learner.

Comment: @TimLymington - thanks for responding. I had already read all your comments before *binging* you. My thoughts: A) was ironic, flippant, humorous, critical. I doubt Mari-Lou meant to trash the COED, just that it isn't infallible and it's always worth cross-validating B) try another till you get the answer you want? Sorry, missed that one. C) Mari-Lou's actual answer--not, change your online dictionary--but that random order is established, comprehensible, acceptable.

Comment: @TimLymington - I think when people feel misunderstood they have a tendency to defend and entrench themselves into inflexible positions they would otherwise eschew. I think we also tend to personalize disagreements, and I think some of that has happened here. Again, Tim, thank you for responding.